# Javascript to wrap array items in <LI> Tag

Tags: javascript

How would I wrap each item of an array in `<LI>` tag using javascript and show it as an ordered or unordered list?

I have an array in javascript like (Test1,test2,test3)

I want to show all elemnts of the array as list items

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I believe this is a similar SO question which has a good answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6326424/1415352

Answer (score 0):

> How would I wrap the each item of an array in `<LI>` Tag using javascript?

Assuming that the array contains DOM node objects:

```
var li, i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(arr[i]);
    arr[i] = li;
}
```

> And show it as a ordered or unordered list?

Add a line:

```
someList.appendChild(li);
```

... inside the for loop. If you are doing that, you may not want to change the value in the array itself (so remove the `arr[i] =` line).

Comment: I think you need to create a text node from each array item before appending.

Comment: @999 - That depends on what the array contains, the question does not specify. I stated the assumptions that the answer depends on just before the code.

Comment: Sorry, only read the code and the OP's question. I see what you stated now.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var liElement = document.createElement('li');
    liElement.appendChild(myArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: You need something like `liElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myArray[i]));`